# Parse a file in c++ and ignore some characters

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a file that has the following information

```
test_wall ; Comments!!
je,5
forward
goto,1
test_random;
je,9
```

I'm supposed to ignore comments after the ";" and move on to the next line. When there is a comma I'm trying to ignore the comma and store the second value.

```
string c;
int a;

c=getChar();

ifstream myfile (filename);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   while ( c != ';' && c != EOF)
   {
       c = getchar();
       if( c == ',')
       {
         a= getChar();
       }

   }
}
myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Your `getchar` calls aren't referencing the stream - they'll wait for standard input (e.g. keyboard).

Comment: how can I ignore the comma also??

Comment: It seems like you need `std::string line; while (getline(myfile, line) { std::string::size_type comma_pos = line.find(','); std::string::size_type semicolon_pos = line.find(';'); if (pos != std::string::npos && (semicolon_pos == std::string::npos || semicolon_pos > comma_pos)) store(line[comma_pos + 1]); }`

Comment: You need to write your code to read **lines** from the file, then you need to search the line for commas and semi-colons. Your problem description says it 'move on to the next line' but the code you wrote doesn't use lines at all.

Comment: General hint: you would have found far superior answers if you had specified your actual problem (what you are trying to achieve). The way you are going about it now, has the classical signs of a suboptimal approach, but... we can't tell: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm sorry everyone for not expressing my question properly. I will try to put in more details in the near future. THank you everyone for the input and the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code. I'm not entirely sure I've understood the problem correctly, but if not hopefully this will set you on the right direction.

```
ifstream myfile (filename);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   // read one line at a time until EOF
   string line;
   while (getline(myFile, line))
   {
       // does the line have a semi-colon?
       size_t pos = line.find(';');
       if (pos != string::npos)
       {
           // remove the semi-colon and everything afterwards
           line = line.substr(0, pos);
       }
       // does the line have a comma?
       pos = line.find(',');
       if (pos != string::npos)
       {
           // get everything after the comma
           line = line.substr(pos + 1);
           // store the string
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

I've left the section commented 'store the string' blank because I'm not certain what you want to do here. Possibly you are asking to convert the string into an integer before storing it. If so then add that code, or ask if you don't know how to do that. Actually don't ask, *search* on stack overflow, because that question has been asked hundreds of times.